# How to know which module function imported in flutter package

Tags: flutter

native background in the javascript import module which is seen from the top of the code like this

```
import {some_fun} from "some_package";
```

but in dart how to find which module is imported from which package for e.g.

```
import "package/material.dart";
and many more
```

how to know which package contain which function or classes

Answer (score 0):

To find that out. In Android Studio or VSCode just hover over the name of the package you are importing. In this case 'package/material.dart' and press ctrl+click.

It will redirect you to the code and you can see all the functions,classes and variables. Just remember anything starting with _(underscore) is private and can not be used in other classes. However if they have setters and getters defined for them then they can be accessed.